# Richfaces : How to not sort an Index Column (rowKeyVar) in rich:datatable when another is sorted

Tags: sorting, jsf-2, datatable, richfaces

With Richfaces 4.3, when you sort a datatable by a column is there a way to display an index that won't be sorted by the column sort method call.
I was using `rowKeyVar="rowkey"` to display the index...

```
<rich:column>
       <f:facet name="header">  
       <h:outputText value="IndexColumn" />
       </f:facet>
       <h:outputText value="rowkey" />
 </rich:column>
```

But when you sort by another column , indexColumn is sorted too...
Thanks